# 'UserForm' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django

I'm working on a django 1.10 project and i am trying to create a view to register new users. Here is my view :

```
class UserFormView(View):
form_class = UserForm
template_name = 'utilisateur/registration.html'

# /Build in fonction for get request/
# /Display a blank form/
def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

# /Build in fonction for post request/
# /Process form data/
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    # /Check validity of data given/
    if form.is_valid():
        # /Create the object user for the form/
        user = form.save(commit=False)

        # /Normalize data/
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']

        # /Editable password/
        user.set_password(password)

        user.save()

        # /Check if these data already exist in de db/
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                # Here you can request something you'd show
                # About the user e.g: photo etc..

                # /Redirect to home page/
                return redirect('utilisateur:index')

    # /Blank form if user not exist/
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Here is my url file:

```
 # /RegisterPage/
url(r'register', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
```

Here is my forms file:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(label="Mot de passe", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

The problem is, when on the registration page, i got an error saying : 'UserForm' object has no attribute 'get'.
I dont see what i have done wrong, can somebody help me ?
Thank you!

Comment: It seems your code is badly indented. The `get` method should be inside the UserFormView class whereas here it is outside with the current indentation. But maybe it is just a mispaste?